# why does this require quadratic formula to solve H(t) = 0?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

In the process of high school math, I bumped into a question regarding quadratic formula. Although the process says it requires to solve $H(t)$, it does  not allow it to be solved simply by plugging making it into
$$0=-16t^2+80t+40$$
I also do not understand how the quadratic function leads to getting the results of $$H(t) = 0$$
The [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3jQU.png) and the [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atgso.png) here . Can someone clarify this please. It is the question c of Example 9.

Comment: $H(t) = 0$ does not mean set $t = 0$. I don't know if that's what you're asking.

Comment: It is not clear what your question is asking. Quite obviously $t=0$ cannot be the answer since at $t=0$ the ball is not at ground level, so this part "*be solved simply by plugging $0$ into it*" does not make sense.

Comment: $H(t) = 0$ means the time *t* when the **height** *H* is zero, that is why you need to solve a quadratic to find *t*

Comment: thank you all for the responses.
I have tried to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$H(t)=−16t^2+80t+40$ can be translate as the height, $h$ of the balls at certain time, $t$. So, you can either find the height at certain time, or find time of certain height. For example, what is the height of the ball when time is $10$? Another example is, what is the time when the height is $60$?

$H(t)=0$ refers to the time when the height of the ball is $0$. So, in order to find the exact time when when the height of the ball is $0$, then just substitute the equation into:

$$H(t)=−16t^2+80t+40$$
$$0=−16t^2+80t+40$$

So, this function is becomes a quadratic equation and you can solve the equation and get $t$ value that shows the time when the height of the ball is $0$. If you also want to find the time when the height is $40$, just substitute the equation into:

$$H(t)=−16t^2+80t+40$$
$$40=−16t^2+80t+40$$
$$0=−16t^2+80t$$

**Edited**

So, from the comment below, this is how you solve $H(t)=0$. Just use quadratic formula.

From :
$$0=−16t^2+80t+40$$

Find the value of $a$,$b$ and $c$ to substitute into quadratic formula :
$$a=-16$$
$$b=80$$
$$c=40$$

Applying into quadratic formula :
$$t=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a},\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
$$t=\frac{-80+\sqrt{\left(80\right)^2-4\left(-16\right)\left(40\right)}}{2\left(-16\right)},\frac{-80-\sqrt{\left(80\right)^2-4\left(-16\right)\left(40\right)}}{2\left(-16\right)}$$
$$t=\frac{-80+\sqrt{6400+2560}}{-32},\frac{-80-\sqrt{6400+2560}}{-32}$$
$$t=\frac{-80+\sqrt{8960}}{-32},\frac{-80-\sqrt{8960}}{-32}$$
$$t=\frac{-80+\sqrt{256\times 35}}{-32},\frac{-80-\sqrt{256\times \:35}}{-32}$$
$$t=\frac{-80+16\sqrt{35}}{-32},\frac{-80-16\sqrt{35}}{-32}$$
$$t=\left(2.5-0.5\sqrt{35}\right),\left(2.5+0.5\sqrt{35}\right)$$
$$t=-0.45803,5.45803$$

$t$ is time and time cannot be negative, so $$t=5.45803$$

Comment: Thank you. I have attempted in solving that, which got me to t = ±√5, but that does not seem to match the answer of 5.458.  Do you have any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: I do edited my answer and add the additional answer which is how to solve the equation. Thank you.

Comment: I do appreciate if you can accept my answer as the best answer

Answer (score 0):

Note that the upward direction has been taken as positive, and $t$ starts when from a height of $ 40m$,the ball is thrown upwards (hence at velocity $80$ m/s), so the height at time *t* will be given by

$H(t) = 40+ 80t - \frac12\cdot32t^2$

Since H will be zero when it hits the ground, we gave

$0 = 40+80t -\frac12\cdot32t^2$

Solve, and screen for feasible value